# Is it mandatory, for a dual citizen, to have a NICOP to enter/exit Pakistan

Tags: paperwork, dual-nationality, pakistani-citizens

The person (minor child) in question is a dual citizen (Pakistan/USA). He has valid passports of both countries. I am aware of the question on [how to use two passports while traveling](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel).

I want to know if he really needs a [NICOP](https://www.nadra.gov.pk/identity/identity-nicop/) to enter/exit Pakistan or will his Pakistani passport suffice. Is it the law that all Pakistanis having dual nationality require a NICOP? If there is, can someone please provide a reference to it.

I have scoured the internet, nadra and the D.C. embassy website for information but can't find anything. Furthermore, the Pakistani embassy never picks up a phone call.

Does anyone here have relevant/recent experience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either your Pakistan passport OR a NICOP. You don't need a NICOP if you have a passport. However, you will generally be required to have a foreign passport if you're travelling on your NICOP.

This thread: https://www.siasat.pk/forums/threads/question-for-overseas-pakistanis.362036/

Answer (score 4):

According to TIMATIC, the database used by check-in staff at airports, you need:

a. Pakistani passport

**or**

b. Foreign passport **and** NICOP.